# Select mathematical from mysql and order by them

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I trying to ORDER result by select. Is that possible?

```
SELECT *,(row1/row2/row3/row4) as order111 FROM `ad` ORDER BY `order111` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but this should work:

```
SELECT *,(row1/row2/row3/row4) as order111 
FROM `ad` 
ORDER BY (row1/row2/row3/row4) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it?

```
SELECT *
     , (row1/row2/row3/row4) AS order111
FROM ad
ORDER BY order111 ASC
```

is acceptable in MySQL.